# C++ How to get std::time_t from strptime()

Tags: c++, datetime

I have a string representing a UTC datetime: `2022-08-24 11:09:24` and I'd like to convert this in to Epoch seconds. So I'm trying to convert the string to a `time_t` and then the `time_t` represents seconds since Epoch.

To do this I'm using `strptime()`:

```
std::string my_time_str("2022-08-24 11:09:24")

struct tm tim = {};
            
strptime(my_time_str.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tim);
```

However, I'm struggling because most examples I find then use `mktime()`, not `gmtime()`. The latter requires a `time_t` object, which is what I'm trying to obtain.

How do I obtain `time_t` from `strptime()`?

I'm using C++ but obviously there's an overlap with C for the datetime functions.

Comment: And what is the problem you have with using `std::mktime`?

Comment: `mktime()` is local time whereas I'm after UTC

Comment: By the way, `strptime` is not a standard C (or C++) function. And it's a C function, so you can't use a `std::string` object with it.

Comment: Set the timezone to GMT/UTC first before calling `std::mktime`? See the example in [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That example sets the system environment variable to UTC.

Comment: Unrelated: It's not `struct tm` in C++. It's `std::tm` and you should probably initialize it like this: `std::tm tim = {.tm_isdst = -1};`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, will update my code

Comment: I tell you C stdlib time utils is a mess, and you don't want to use it - like 31'st February 2020 is a perfectly fine date. Try std::chrono::parse (C++20), or Boost Date_Time, or some reliable library if you only have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using my [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono-preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which works with C++11/14/17:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::string my_time_str("2022-08-24 11:09:24");
    std::istringstream in{std::move(my_time_str)};
    date::sys_seconds tim;
    in >> date::parse("%F %T", tim);
    std::time_t tt = tim.time_since_epoch().count();
    std::cout << tt << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1661339364
```

If you have C++20, and a std::lib that has implemented it, the above ports to C++20 simply by dropping `#include "date/date.h"` and changing `date::` to `std::chrono::` in two places.

I could have also used `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` as the format string, but chose `"%F %T"` instead just because it is easier to type.  The latter is nothing but a shortcut for the former.